# laravel Maatwebsite\Excel 3.1 locked cell

Tags: phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

referring from official documentation [laravel excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html) implementing styles can refer from [PhpSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#valid-array-keys-for-style-applyfromarray) and i succeed try to make a row bold.
then how can we protect some columns from being edited ?
I've tried use `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection` and implementing `lock` but seem doesn't work

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
class someExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithStyles
{
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            // Style the first row as bold text and disable Column A for edited
            1 => ['font' => ['bold' => true]],
            'A' => [
                'protection' => [
                    'locked' => true,
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * function headings()
     * function array()
     * some source array
     */
}
```

Comment: Hello have you tried looking at https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/1349 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full implementation from [PhpSpreadSheet Setting security on a spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet) look like this

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

class someExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithStyles
{
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        // Make sure you enable worksheet protection if you need any of the worksheet or cell protection features!
        $sheet->getParent()->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
        
        // lock all cells then unlock the cell
        $sheet->getParent()->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('T2:T10')
            ->getProtection()
            ->setLocked(Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);

        // styling first row
        $sheet->getStyle(1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    }

    /**
     * function headings()
     * function array()
     * some source array
     */
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way of just locking specific cell instead of locking the entire sheet and then unlocking the specific cells you want? I searched the entire web and de library source code for it and couldn't find it. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ThallesPortilho I just found it on the documentation and direct implement it